# Reacting to StylusDown in control's UI?

Tags: wpf, templates, touch, stylus-pen

I'm building a touch screen application in WPF and I'm wanting to show a change in UI when the user presses a button with their finger/stylus.  Currently you only get a flicker of UI change once the finger is released but nothing before that.

I've been trying to hook up triggers and/or eventtriggers in the button template to things like stylusdown and touchdown but to no avail.

I've hooked up some console writes on events attached to a button and they appear in the following order:

- StylusDown
- StylusButtonDown
- TouchDown
- StylusUp
- StylusButtonUp
- Click

All of which firing at the same time when the finger is lifted from the screen. (TouchUp doesn't seem to fire at all).

Any ideas on how I could begin to capture a finger pressing onto a button in the template so I can give the user some idea that they are actually pressing a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [blogging in more detail](http://www.triballabs.net/2011/03/reactive-ui-in-windows-touch-and-surface/) about this issue I had a comment recommending using a SurfaceWindow and then SurfaceButtons from the Surface Toolkit (currently in Beta) and now all is working as I would expect.

Update: The link is now dead. Here's the [link to that page from Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150516045121/http://triballabs.net/2011/03/reactive-ui-in-windows-touch-and-surface/).